# printing documents is slow on 64 bit windows machine when compared with 32 bit windows machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, printing, printer

I have developed a Windows Service using C# which prints the documents from my C# windows application. The service prints the documents fast when my printer is connected to windows 32 bit machine(windows 2003 OS) but the printing slows down when the printer is connected to windows 64 bit machine(windows 2008 OS).i.e the number of pages printed per minute is less on win 2008 when compared to win 2003

Can some one please help me out to make my documents printing speed same on both Operating systems,

Thanks & Regards
Chaithanya

Comment: The number of pages printed per minute isn't handled by any operating system.  The document is sent to the printer.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the printer Setting are different. For example, sending custom fonts as graphics to the printer will slow down printing.

Please specify the model of your printer and how it is connected to your computer.